# How to select recent three reviews for each business?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| businees_id | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rating      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| author_name | varchar(60)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| author_url  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| review      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| review_date | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

here is my query:

```
Select * from mytable limit 0,3
```

Above is the structure of my table. I need to select last three review for all businesses.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Select * from mytable limit 0, 3

Answer (score 1):

This query ought to do it. `table_name` is the name of your table. `ORDER BY review_date DESC` instructs MySQL to sort by date newest->oldest. `LIMIT 3` truncates results to just the first three.

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY review_date DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: It only return three rows. I need last three for all business

Answer (score 0):

See [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

```
set @num := 0, @businees_id := '';

select type, variety, price
from (
   select id, businees_id, rating,  author_name, author_url, review, review_date,
      @num := if(@businees_id = businees_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @businees_id := businees_id as dummy
  from mytable
  order by businees_id, review_date DESC
) as x where x.row_number <= 3;
```